# How can we auto generate various sized grid columns with CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on a grid layout that squishes from a single row into a single column as the screen size shrinks using the `repeat(auto-fill, minmax())` algorithm.  I have it broken down into 3 grids because they'll ultimately be spread across 2 Angular components.

Here's an example of my code so far and a [codepen to tinker with](https://codepen.io/Optiq/pen/oNXXPxv?editors=1100).

```css
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}

.parent{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 480px));
  background-color: #888;
}

.mainGrid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, 240px));
}

.labelGrid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, 120px));
}

.indexNumber{
  width: 40px;
  /*min-width: 10px;
  max-width: 120px;*/
}

.button-area{
  justify-self: right;
}
```

```html
 <section>

  <section class="parent">

<p class="indexNumber">13</p>

<article class="mainGrid">

  <label class="labelGrid">
    <span class="labelText">text input</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>

  <label class="labelGrid">
    <span class="labelText">text input 2</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>

</article>

<article class="button-area">
  <button>delete</button>
</article>

  </section>

</section>
```

So Far the behavior of the `.mainGrid` works as desired but in the `.parentGrid` it places everything into rows rather than collapsing down as you shrink the width of the page.  I'm guessing it's because the values of the nested grids are resulting as something too wide to fit all in one row in the `.parentGrid`.

I've been back and forth trying to get this to work by trying to figure out if there's a way to make the columns generate at different widths depending on the content.  There's no reason for why the `<p>13</p>` should be in a column 200px+ wide.  I'm trying to find a way to make this behavior occur automatically to avoid making a media query.  I experimented with `min-content` which did the trick, but it took away the responsiveness as well as minimizing my inputs into a single row no matter how wide you expand the screen.

The order of behavior I'm trying to achieve starting from a wide screen shrinking to a narrow screen goes as follows.

1. All items on single row.
2. Text inside labels stacks on top of the inputs.
3. Inputs stack on top of one another.
4. Parent grid stacks items into rows with the `<p>` on top and the `<button>` on the bottom.

Does anybody know how this behavior can be achieved while eliminating all the excessive space being wasted?